# Export list of computer from txt to CSV as column headers PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, export-to-csv

```
function listcomputers {
    $computers = Get-Content 'D:\computer\Scheduled_Tills.txt'
    $results = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

    foreach ($computer in $computers) {
        $results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{'Device'=($computer)}
    }
    $results | Export-Csv -Path $resultCSV -NoTypeInformation
}
```

I want to take a list of devices in txt I have and display them as column header in CSV.

For example

```
EXCEL COLUMN A | COLUMN B | COLUMN C | COLUMN D | etc
ROW 1 device 1 | device 2 | device 3 | device 4 | etc
```

I don't want to display them as a list like this

```
EXCEL COLUMN A | COLUMN B | COLUMN C | COLUMN D | etc
ROW 1 device 1 |
ROW 2 device 2 |
ROW 3 device 3 |
```

Furthermore, I don't know the x number of devices I will have so it could be 10 or could be up to 100

I searched online and tried so much and I am struggling really badly.

Answer (score 0):

Join your devices list to a single comma-separated string and write it to a file via `Set-Content` or `Out-File`:

```
(Get-Content 'D:\computer\Scheduled_Tills.txt') -join ',' |
    Set-Content $resultCSV
```